# 'Audio' is not defined, and 'document' is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to add some music to my webpage (only mute/unmute button) but I don`t know how to do it

HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Mymusic.js"></script>
    <div class="audiodiv">
    <img src="img/Speaker.png" id="mutebtn">
    </div>
```

The Javascript document:

```
var audio, mutebtn;
function initAudioPlayer(){
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "audio/MyAudio.mp3";
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.play();
    mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
    mutebtn.addEventListener("click", mute);
    function mute(){
        if(audio.muted){
            audio.muted = false;
            document.getElementById("mutebtn").src = "img/Speaker.png"
        } else {
            audio.muted = true;
            document.getElementById("mutebtn").src = "img/Muted.png"
        }
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
```

I get two error messages saying 'Audio' is not defined and 'document' is not defined. What`s wrong?

Comment: I can't replicate your issue.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it could be wrong? A friend of mine did exactly the same and it works for him

Comment: Not really. Do you have another computer you can try this on?

Comment: No. As I already said a friend of mine uses the same code and it works fine for him, so I don`t have a clue why this is not working for me

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I`ve tried both Chrome and Safari, but it doesn`t work on any of them. I`m using the latest version of Dreamweaver